# How to perform login authentication with clean architecture

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, clean-architecture

I have application in which login part comes as a separate tab in mobile. I need to do token authentication ,so i will pass username,password entered from textfield , client id, client secret and grant type. I will receive access token, refresh token, expires in, token type and scope. Now i need to pass this access token to all the requests. Once the token expired, i need to use refresh token to get new access token. If the refresh token expired, i need to return log in page. How to achieve this in application with clean architecture . In Data repository , i need to include the api calls and need to connect with lib screens.

Anyone can provide the sample?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So as I understood,

In the presentation layer, you can have the text fields which take user input. These are passed to the usecases in the domain layer. Finally, in the data layer, you can directly make API calls with the parameters you receive.

In the usecase for login, when it hits the data layer and receives `access token, refresh token, expires in, token type and scope` as the response, then these can be saved in the data layer.

There can be a function in the data layer to validate the access token, if the access token is expired then it must call another function to get a new token with the refresh token. If even the refresh token is expired then throw a user-defined exception which is understood by the view that it must return to the login screen.

To create a user-defined exception:

```
class UserDefinedException implements Exception {}
```

Comment: hi sir permission to ask. If I need the data from the successful response to login to use user verification/ send OTP. How to send the data to use in BLOC Verification? Is it by bringing the data in Navigation, is it clean?